# Error in starting discord with betterdiscord

Tags: discord

I have an error while starting discord:

```
Uncaught error: syntax error: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Discord\app.0.0.309\resources\app\betterdiscord\config.js Unexpected token
```

I honestly don't mind if I have to uninstall BD but I just need to know how or possibly get it fixed without uninstalling it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this bug report](https://github.com/rauenzi/BetterDiscordApp/issues/454) on their github, you can just reinstall BD to get it to work again.